# Custom AccessDeniedHandler: How to control the logging of AccessDeniedException

Tags: spring, spring-security

I have written a custom `AccessDeniedHandler` (look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41633492/7095884) answer) and it works fine . But I wonder, why the `AccessDeniedException` is still logged in the background:

```
org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException: Zugriff verweigert
    at org.springframework.security.access.vote.AffirmativeBased.decide(AffirmativeBased.java:84)
    at org.springframework.security.access.intercept.AbstractSecurityInterceptor.beforeInvocation(AbstractSecurityInterceptor.java:233)
```

How to suppress this logging? Or better: How can I control, when to log this message and when not?

Comment: What logging framework do you use? Is there a relevant line before the stacktrace?

Comment: I'm using Log4J. What do you mean by relevant line? The two lines before are `org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher invoke` and 
`Schwerwiegend: Servlet.service() for servlet appServlet threw exception`.