# Azure B2C custom policy doesn't work in Safari

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c

Azure B2C custom policy sometime fails only in Safari browser with error:

```
ServerError: AADB2C90091: The user has cancelled entering self-asserted information.
```

In other browsers, like Chrome or Edge, works perfectly.

For sign-in flow, I use this template https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master/policies/custom-sm-displaycontrol/policy.

Answer (score 0):

Cause of  `ServerError: AADB2C90091`, according to  [User canceled the operation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/troubleshoot?pivots=b2c-user-flow#user-canceled-the-operation):

- A user policy uses the suggested self-service password reset (SSPR) experience with a consumer's local account. The user selects the **Forgot your password** link and then selects `Cancel` button before the user flow experience completes.

To resolve `ServerError: AADB2C90091`, according to [Guidelines for using custom page content](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/customize-ui-with-html?pivots=b2c-user-flow#guidelines-for-using-custom-page-content):

- Supported browser version is Safari for iOS and macOS, version 12 and above
- Due to security restrictions, Azure AD B2C **does not support** `frame`, `iframe`, or `form` HTML elements.

References: [Cancel button throws error on Azure AD B2C Policy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71531368/spring-boot-cancel-button-throws-error-on-azure-ad-b2c-policy), [Sign up Sign in Error on Cancel](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/9486757c-ba0a-4c03-85e3-b41a2eac021e/sign-up-sign-in-error-on-cancel?forum=WindowsAzureAD), and [showCancelButton](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/49984)